# How do I restart my Animal Crossing game?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

When playing the game I was being an absolute idiot, and I named my town "Shopping" because I saw the question, "Where are you headed", how do I delete my data so I can start over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reboot the game, and all at the same time, press a y x and b. It will come up with the usual message, "Are you sure" blah blah blah. After doing this you will have restarted your whole game.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked, thanks. Also good job for the fast response!

Comment: @ShovelKnight but I gotta say, Shopping is a great name for a town. :D